# typo3: how could i see the contents that certain user edit in the backend?

Tags: typo3

I am using TYPO3 4.5.23, when i login /typo3 admin site, over one page, it shows `The BE-USER Tom began to edit content on this page 4 min ago`, So my question is: is there a way that I can see what Tom edit on this page?

Answer (score 0):

You see this message per record base. So if you get this message, you usually should see it on the page-record, or on some tt_content elements etc. In list-view the icon is shown on each record which has been edited.

If you edit an record, there will be a notice.

This message disappears after two hours. If an user log out, the message is not removed (missing feature;)! But if an editor close (or save & close) an record, this message will disapear. Teach your editors to close records.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see exactly what Tom edited (not just which content element, but which content he changed), use the "History/Undo" tool. Right-click the page in the tree and click "History/Undo". There you see all the changes that have been made in a diff-like view and also the user that made the change.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to see a system-wide log for all changes that have been made by this user, just log in as admin and click on "Admin Tools" and then on "Log" in the menu on the left. Then you will get a dropdown-box for all users in your Typo3-backend and you can choose the desired user and see all the changes that he has ever made.